# Output shows symbols too thick. (QGIS 3.8.2)

Tags: qgis, symbology, export

I've loaded data from a CSV-file without problem and assigned rule-based symbols to it. These are SVG of my own design with a line thickness set at 0,2 mm (yes, I know that's thin).
Everything looks fine until I export the map. What should be 0,2 mm lines become more like 2 mm, making the symbols quite useless. I've had the problem before and managed to work my way around it, but I'm afraid I don't remember how. I feel like I'm overlooking something rather obvious but have no idea what…. Any ideas?

Right layout
[image]

Wrong output
[image]

Comment: If it helps: by changing the thickness of the lines from 0,2 mm to 1 pixel the lines are too my liking. Still, I really don't understand why setting them to mm does not work.